# How to Import the xml file into out of Box Repository In ATG other than using StartSQLRepository

Tags: import, atg

How can we Import the xml file into out of Box Repository In ATG other than using StartSQLRepository , is there any way of importing the xml file in to the data base ,

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't too large, a common way to do it is to paste it into the repository component in dynamo administration.  All repositories in ATG will have this option in dyn/admin just for this task.

[image]

If that doesn't fit your needs, you can write a class calling atg.repository.xml.AddService.addItem().  From the manual:

> You use the addItem() method of the atg.repository.xml.AddService class to create new repository items from XML documents.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s0603addingrepositoryitems01.html and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGRepositoryGuide/html/s1202addingitems01.html

Answer (score 0):

goto dyn/admin/--/atg/comm/catalog.productCatalog/  -- eg

find the property select. -definition file
use xmlfile("path/to/file);   -- in that text box area

u will get the error msg whn the ATG cannot find the file.
Error msg give the idea where ATG is expecting the file to be
--some config folders.

/ Anilal